# Environment variables containing newlines in Node?

Tags: node.js, escaping, environment-variables

I'm attempting to load an RSA private key into my nodejs application using environment variables, but the newlines seem to be being auto-escaped.

For the following, assume that the `PRIVATE_KEY` env var is set to the following (not my actual key):

```
PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\n37sJ5QsW+sJyoNde3xH8vdXhzU7eT82D6X/scw9RZz+/6rCJ4p0=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

If I call `console.log` directly with the preceding string, I get the following as output:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXAIBAAKBgQCqGKukO1De7zhZj6+H0qtjTkVxwTCpvKe4eCZ0FPqri0cb2JZfXJ/DgYSF6vUp
wmJG8wVQZKjeGcjDOL5UlsuusFncCzWBQ7RKNUSesmQRMSGkVb1/3j+skZ6UtW+5u09lHNsj6tQ5
1s1SPrCBkedbNf0Tp0GbMJDyR4e9T04ZZwIDAQABAoGAFijko56+qGyN8M0RVyaRAXz++xTqHBLh
3tx4VgMtrQ+WEgCjhoTwo23KMBAuJGSYnRmoBZM3lMfTKevIkAidPExvYCdm5dYq3XToLkkLv5L2
pIIVOFMDG+KESnAFV7l2c+cnzRMW0+b6f8mR1CJzZuxVLL6Q02fvLi55/mbSYxECQQDeAw6fiIQX
GukBI4eMZZt4nscy2o12KyYner3VpoeE+Np2q+Z3pvAMd/aNzQ/W9WaI+NRfcxUJrmfPwIGm63il
AkEAxCL5HQb2bQr4ByorcMWm/hEP2MZzROV73yF41hPsRC9m66KrheO9HPTJuo3/9s5p+sqGxOlF
L0NDt4SkosjgGwJAFklyR1uZ/wPJjj611cdBcztlPdqoxssQGnh85BzCj/u3WqBpE2vjvyyvyI5k
X6zk7S0ljKtt2jny2+00VsBerQJBAJGC1Mg5Oydo5NwD6BiROrPxGo2bpTbu/fhrT8ebHkTz2epl
U9VQQSQzY1oZMVX8i1m5WUTLPz2yLJIBQVdXqhMCQBGoiuSoSjafUhV7i1cEGpb88h5NBYZzWXGZ
37sJ5QsW+sJyoNde3xH8vdXhzU7eT82D6X/scw9RZz+/6rCJ4p0=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

You can see that the newline chars are being respected. However, if I call `console.log(process.env["PRIVATE_KEY"])`, the output contains the `\n` literal instead of actual newlines:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\n37sJ5QsW+sJyoNde3xH8vdXhzU7eT82D6X/scw9RZz+/6rCJ4p0=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I've been trying to find more information online about how node processes environment variables with no luck. How do I load this key via env vars while maintaining newline characters? If that's not possible, how can I restore them?

Answer (score 102):

Just replace `\n` before use the value:

```
var private_value = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
console.log(private_value);
```

will result correctly:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: You're a genius! So simple perfect!

Comment: Assumes that you have control of the application code however.

Comment: Brilliant! Simpy worked.
In my case I used
("${System.env.SIGNING_KEY_ID}".replace(/\n/, '\n'))
That nailed it.

Comment: This worked, but I don't understand how. It's replacing `\n` with a `\n` ?

Comment: @NikhilOwalekar it replaces \\n with \n. I had (thanks to @Adriano) the problem with my AWS lambda function and env var.

Comment: why replaces \\n with \n?

Answer (score 22):

[dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#rules) supports newlines with double quotes:

> double quoted values expand new lines
>
> `MULTILINE="new\nline"` becomes
>
> ```
> {MULTILINE: 'new
> line'}
> ```

Comment: This is definitely the accepted answer. Simple and documented.

Answer (score 17):

**Update:** Dotenv supports multiline variables natively as of v15+:

```
PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
Kh9NV...
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

See: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#multiline-values

---

(For Dotenv versions < 15)

If you're using **dotenv**: We solved it this way, with newlines and JSON.parse (**this allows any backslash escaped chars within the string, not just `\n`**):

in .env:

```
MY_KEY='-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nabcde...'
```

in server.ts:

```
myKey = JSON.parse(`"${process.env.MY_KEY}"`), // convert special chars
```

See thread: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/218

Comment: I used this code for some time but suddenly it stopped working and start showing Unexpected token in JSON at position 32 error which points towards the \

Comment: Getting `Unexpected token =`

Answer (score 15):

**Node.js *does* correctly reflect environment variables that have embedded *actual* newlines**, as the following `bash` snippet demonstrates:

```sh
$ PRIVATE_KEY=$'ab\ncde' node -p 'process.env["PRIVATE_KEY"].indexOf("\n")'
2  # 0-based index of the (first) actual newline char. in env. var. 'PRIVATE_KEY'
```

<sup>Note that `$'...'` is a special type of `bash` string in which escape sequences such as `\n` *are* expanded, so in the command above `PRIVATE_KEY` is indeed defined with *2* lines and passed as an environment variable to `node` (simply by prepending the variable assignment to the command to invoke, which is a standard feature in POSIX-like shells).</sup>

A simple way to print the value of an environment variable *verbatim* is:

```sh
# With *verbatim* '\n'
$ X='line 1\nline 2' node -p 'process.env.X'
line1\nline 2

# With *actual newline*, thanks to $'...' interpolation.
$ X=$'line 1\nline 2' node -p 'process.env.X'
line 1
line 2
```

In fact, **Node doesn't interpret the value of environment variables in any way** (which is the right thing to do).

**It must be that your `PRIVATE_KEY` variable doesn't contain actual *newlines*, but  `\n` *literals* (a `\` char. followed by char. `n`).**

- If the assignment command `PRIVATE_KEY="..."` in the question is a *shell* command, that would explain it: In POSIX-like shells such as `bash`, `\n` inside a `"..."` string is left *as-is*.

  - By contrast, *JavaScript* `"..."` strings *do* interpolate escape sequences such as `\n`, which is why passing such a string directly to `console.log()` indeed outputs newlines; e.g., `node -e 'console.log("ab\ncde")'` indeed outputs *2* lines.
- `PRIVATE_KEY="ab\ncde" node -p 'process.env["PRIVATE_KEY"]'` (literally) outputs `ab\ncde`, showing that `\n` was retained as a literal.

You have two options to fix your problem:

- **Preferably, define your environment variable with actual newlines to begin with** - see below.
- **Alternatively, if you do not control how the environment variable is set**, expand the `\n` literals to actual newlines in your Node.js (JavaScript) code: see [Adriano Godoy's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36439803/45375).

---

To **define `PRIVATE_KEY` with actual newlines in POSIX-like shells**, use one of the following techniques:

- `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`: use an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

```sh
export PRIVATE_KEY=$'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n....\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
```

- others, such as `dash` (and from any shell script that uses `sh`):

```sh
export PRIVATE_KEY="$(printf %s '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n....\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----')"
```

Alternatively, for better readability you can use a command substitution with a here-document:

```sh
export PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat <<'EOF'
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOF
)"
```

Finally, as [Allen Luce's answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30403836/45375), POSIX-compatible shells allow even *regular string literals* to span multiple lines, though readability may suffer a bit:

```sh
export PRIVATE_KEY='-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
```

Comment: Thanks for being the only answer that really explains what's happening.

Answer (score 7):

It may be easier to see what's actually going on by inspecting rather than printing:

```
% export X="hey\nman"
% node
> process.env['X']
'hey\\nman'
>
```

Node's REPL implicitly applies the [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-options) method which emits an escaped string. That shows the literal backslash and lower-case "n" that the environment variable contains. So what's being fed to `console.log` is more like this:

```
> console.log("hey\\nman")
hey\nman
```

One option (in most popular shells) is to embed newlines straight into a variable just by hitting enter within a quoted string:

```
% export X="hey
> man"
% node
> process.env['X']
'hey\nman'
> console.log(process.env['X'])
hey
man
undefined
>
```

This technique also works within script files, just use newlines within quotes. If you have to take the environmental variables as-is a common approach is use string replacement:

```
% export X="hey\nman\ndude\nwhat"
% node
> console.log(process.env['X'].replace(/\\n/g, '\n'))
hey
man
dude
what
```

Comment: ++, but the phrase "Node will ... escape them to avoid interpolation" is misleading and suggests a misconception. Node doesn't - and shouldn't - apply string interpolation to environment variables. The escaping you're seeing is an artifact of the Node REPL: when you print a string or variable just by submitting it, without `console.log()`, the REPL _at that point_ actively encodes the value as a JavaScript string for convenient reuse in JavaScript source code. Thus, if the REPL shows you `a\\nb`, it means that the string _literally_ contains `\n` (i.e., characters `\ ` and `n`).

Comment: The prompt char. (`%`) in your shell code suggest `csh`, but the use of `export` suggests a POSIX-like shell.
In POSIX-like shells, `"hey\nman"` will _not_ create a newline between `hey` and `man`. Using `echo` to print the value can muddle the picture, because `echo` in some POSIX-like shells
does interpret escape sequences. A shell-neutral way to print the value as-is is `printf %s "$X"`. To reiterate the previous point: whatever the value assigned by the shell is,
Node.js will use _uninterpreted_ (even though the Node.js REPL may apply escaping for _display_ purposes).

Comment: Not sure how you thought I was saying `"hey\nman"` creates a newline, I'm demonstrating that it does not. The point about `echo` is a good one so I removed that. Also clarified to make it clear how Node escapes the string.

Comment: That there was confusion around literal `\n` vs. actual newlines was evidenced by  your since-removed `echo $X` example. I'm glad you removed it. A simple way to take diagnostic output out of the picture and echo the value verbatim: `X='hey\nman' node -p 'process.env.X'` vs. `X=$'hey\nman' node -p 'process.env.X'`

Answer (score 6):

As described in another topic you can encode yout multiline string in base64 and put it inside .env like

```
HTTPS_CA_CERTIFICATE=LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSURDVENDQWZHZ0F3SUJBZ0lVY29lWFp1R
```

And then decode it inside your app

```
var cert = new Buffer(process.env.HTTPS_CA_CERTIFICATE, 'base64').toString('ascii');
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using:

```
JSON.parse(`"${process.env.PUBPEM}"`)
```

which suddenly started to fail.
So I changed it to:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(process.env.PUBPEM))
```

Which solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone out there trying to use multi-line variable (i.e RSA private keys) in a dotenv file (should work for any configuration file though).

1) make each line of the private key end with a \n

```
  such that first line**\n**
  second line**\n**
  and the  third line and so on
```

2) now make the variable in single line in double quotes as follow
  KEY="such that first line**\n**second line**\n**and the  third line and so on**\n**"

3) **Ensure** you add a leading and trailing \n character for the key as well 
KEY="**\n**such that first line**\n**second line**\n**and the  third line and so on**\n**"

4) now in your code (i.e node, of course if you do not have access to code you have rely on the behaviour of the platform/app)

goodlyRepresentedKey = (process.env.KEY).replace(/\n/g, '\n');

(if biggly why not goodly)