# How can I use Google default credentials on Heroku without the JSON file?

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-api, google-authentication

I'm looking to deploy a Node app to Heroku, and the key challenge I'm running into has to do with the Google default authorization workflow for Node. By default, Google looks for a JSON file with secret keys, with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` as the environmental variable name that points to the path of this JSON file. That is fine for local development, but in production I naturally do not want to commit this sensitive JSON file to source.  Heroku allows you to create environmental variables, but each variable is individual. Somehow I need to break up this JSON file into individual variables, but I don't know what to call them for Google to recognize them.

[There is a similar thread on this for Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35929650/how-can-i-authorize-a-google-service-account-without-the-default-credentials-fil), but the equivalent does not work in Node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getApplicationDefault` method is really just a convenience factory for finding the right client. You can actually [construct your client directly](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/master/lib/auth/googleauth.js#L476), passing in the parameters read from [environmental variables defined in Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application).

Take this example which I used recently with a Heroku deployment:

```
const GoogleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

function authorize() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const authFactory = new GoogleAuth();
        const jwtClient = new authFactory.JWT(
            process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL, // defined in Heroku
            null,
            process.env.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY, // defined in Heroku
            ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
        );

        jwtClient.authorize(() => resolve(jwtClient));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 11):

When using the google translation api, I ran into the same issue. I was unable to reference the whole JSON file, so I created two env variables in Heroku and referenced them in a credentials object. You can not have them stand alone. The .replace for the private key is an important detail. You should paste in that full key as is on Heroku.

```
const Translate = require('@google-cloud/translate');
const projectId = 'your project id here';

const translate = new Translate({
  projectId: projectId,
  credentials: {
    private_key: process.env.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
    client_email: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL
  }
});
```

Comment: This is the way I got my app to work with Heroku, thanks a lot for posting. They outline a similar approach in a [Google APIs doc post](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#loading-credentials-from-environment-variables) for authenticating directly with source control cloud deployment, but couldn't find anywhere in the docs how to authenticate Translate() with the env variables. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

thanks! i also found another solution in case it helps others:

// Authenticating on a global basis.
var projectId = process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT; // E.g. 'grape-spaceship-123'

var gcloud = require('google-cloud')({
  projectId: projectId,

credentials: require('./path/to/keyfile.json')

});

this way you can deconstruct the entire json key provided by auth

Answer (score 1):

I was just dealing with the same issue and couldn't find a solution online that I could get to work, so I made my own. I know this is an old issue, but wanted to share, so others might find it down the road.

To solve this problem, I used Node JS to programmatically write the file to the host after deployment by accessing the secret key values in my environment variables.

First, I created an object to behave as a JSON template in my JS code with the correct key names and used my environment variables to get the key values in that object. With that template in place, I was almost ready to have Node write the file to the host,, but I had one issue to solve.

I discovered [from another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36439803/13604562) that `JSON.stringify()` will modify any backslash ('') that comes from an environment variable into two backslashes ('\') (it will not make this change when a backslash comes from a string in a JavaScript object). This was a problem for me because my private key had 28 backslashes. To correct this, as documented in the link above, I retrieved the value of the environment variable and updated the object before passing the object through `JSON.stringify()`.

With that issue solved, I was able to write the file to the host and successfully deploy my app without exposing my JSON file on my public repository.

```
const fs = require('fs');

async function createJSONFile() {

  //Replace '\' in environment variable .env file before JSON.stringify() 
  //so that stringify does not turn it into '\\'
  //https://stackoverflow.com/a/36439803/13604562
  jsonFile.private_key = process.env.GCS_JSON_private_key.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');

  let data = JSON.stringify(jsonFile);
  //CHECK IF JSON KEYFILE FOR GCS EXISTS. IF NOT, CREATES FILE
  if (!fs.existsSync(`./${process.env.GCS_KEYFILE}`)) {
    await fs.writeFile(`./${process.env.GCS_KEYFILE}`, data, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json(err);
      }
    });
  }
}

//JSON file template
let jsonFile = {
  type: `${process.env.GCS_JSON_type}`,
  project_id: `${process.env.GCS_JSON_project_id}`,
  private_key_id: `${process.env.GCS_JSON_private_key_id}`,
  private_key: `${process.env.GCS_JSON_private_key}`,
  client_email: `${process.env.GCS_JSON_client_email}`,
  client_id: `${process.env.GCS_JSON_client_id}`,
  auth_uri: `${process.env.GCS_JSON_auth_uri}`,
  token_uri: `${process.env.GCS_JSON_token_uri}`,
  auth_provider_x509_cert_url: `${process.env.GCS_JSON_auth_provider_x509_cert_url}`,
  client_x509_cert_url: `${process.env.GCS_JSON_client_x509_cert_url}`,
};

createJSONFile();
```

Answer (score -2):

Store the private key i heroku without the double quotes , your solution will work.