# node multiline process.env (with and without) dotenv

Tags: node.js

I have this env variable:

```
export MyEnvVar="new\nline"
```

If I run the command "echo -ne $MyEnvVar" on a Mac terminal this is what I get:

> ```
> new
> line
> ```

When I run the following code:

```
require("dotenv").config();
console.log("new\nline");
console.log("");
console.log("");
console.log(process.env.MyEnvVar);
```

The output:

> new
>
> line
>
> new\nline

How can I get process.env.MyEnvVar to have multiline instead of escaping it?

dotenv documentation says it support multi-line vars. https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Very good point @GabrielBleu, question amended to include a quesiton :) How can I get process.env.MyEnvVar to have multiline instead of escaping it?

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400341/environment-variables-containing-newlines-in-node

Comment: it looked like a workaround, dotnev seem to support multiline but I can't get it to work https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv see "new lines are expanded if in double quotes"

Comment: See answer from Allen in above post; One option is to set the variable outside of node with actual newlines

Answer (score 2):

The dotenv library supports new lines. If you use double quotes and the new line character (\n) then the new line character will create a new line.

Example in .env file:

```
SERVER_KEY = "abc\nefg"
```

will become:

```
abc
efg
```