# (node:13672) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

Tags: cryptography, rsa, private-key, pem

I have done research into this error and it seems as though so far nothing is working for me. I am using Node.js and the crypto library. My Private key is stored in a dotenv file like below:

.env file

```
PRIVATE_KEY = -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
ezfvDUlrPehGYvlmQq3ReTk8EiO8N0RDvsJqerZJ91Lb6UBGlOyuv/SaxDxwxx/g
....more lines...
5SRwCCIaByIwAw0HkQx+XnBqW8II2TgTb9MMBQht/Cu5WZKFroagGQO5cgyilQg4
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

index.ts

```
const WM_KEY_PRIVATE = process.env.WM_KEY_PRIVATE;
 
function createSignature(reqHeaders: SecurityHeaders) {
const signer = createSign('RSA-SHA256');
const payload = generateSignatureMap(reqHeaders);
console.log("payload:", payload);
signer.update(payload);
signer.end();
return signer.sign(WM_KEY_PRIVATE, 'base64');
}

function generateSignatureMap(reqHeaders: SecurityHeaders) {
let keys: string[] = Object.keys(reqHeaders).sort();
let vals: string[] = [];

for(let k of keys) {
    vals.push(reqHeaders[k].toString().trim());
}
return vals.join('\n') + '\n';
// let keys = reqHeaders.toString()
// return keys
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get rid of this error? Should I not use .env to store the key? I have read where keys in this format are difficult to load from .env files, but I have not come across a real solid solution for this. I have tried making it all one line too. Any help in understanding this will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use doublequotes and backslash-n (on one line); dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284126/node-multiline-process-env-with-and-without-dotenv . https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/pull/486 indicates that a syntax more like you want, and in ruby, is coming perhaps soon.

Comment: Thank you @dave_thompson_085. I did try your solution and I have seen it work for other  people. For some reason, it did not work for me. Instead I had to "npm install fs" (backend is Node.js) and use that library to read the PEM file with the private key. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error -- `error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line` -- using libcrypto (OpenSSL) in C. So a different environment but perhaps this could be useful for someone else.

In my case I had the certificate in a string and conversion to an X509 type always failed. But it worked when the certificate was read from file.

The problem was the lack of `\n` as @dave_thompson_085 suggested in a comment to the OP's question.

### Doesn't work: no `\n`

```
static const char *C1 = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"
"MIIEoTCCAwmgAwIBAgIJANEHdl0yo7CWMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMH4xCzAJBgNV"
(...)
"tQAVo+yVgLgV2Hws73Fc0o3wC78qPEA+v2aRs/Be3ZFDgDyghc/1fgU+7C+P6kbq"
"d4poyb6IW8KCJbxfMJvkordNOgOUUxndPHEi/tb/U7uLjLOgPA=="
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
```

### Fixed version

```
static const char *C1 = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
"MIIEoTCCAwmgAwIBAgIJANEHdl0yo7CWMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMH4xCzAJBgNV\n"
(...)
"tQAVo+yVgLgV2Hws73Fc0o3wC78qPEA+v2aRs/Be3ZFDgDyghc/1fgU+7C+P6kbq\n"
"d4poyb6IW8KCJbxfMJvkordNOgOUUxndPHEi/tb/U7uLjLOgPA==\n"
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
```

Note the `\n` at the end of each line.